# Get Cognito verification code in lambda to send SMS using local provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I want to send verification code to the users mobile as SMS using a local provider in my country without using AWS SNS.

I have a trigger in CustomMessage and lambda function is working fine. But my problem I am unable to find verification code in lambda function.Only find codeParameter which is {####}.

So how can I get the verification code to send it using local provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement Custom Authentication in this scenario. Because Cognito wouldn't share the secret with you. We have implemented Custom Authentication scenario using Cognito Custom authentication mechanism.

you could use DefineAuth,CreateAuth and VerifyAuth triggers for implementation. please refer to the following flow.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/

Comment: Ok. I will check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an alternative solution, I would recommend using Cognito's Custom SMS Sender trigger. When you use custom SMS trigger, you do not have to implement a custom authentication mechanism.

Custom SMS Sender trigger will enable you to get encrypted code parameter, then you can decrypt it using the KMS key you configured for your user pool.

The steps you can follow:

1. Crete a KSM key.
2. Create a Custom SMS Sender lambda function. This function should be able to perform kms:decrypt operation.
3. Implement your custom sms logic in the lambda function. Since you have the code parameter now, this will be very easy.
4. Give your user pool access to invoke custom sms sender function.
5. Set custom sms sender trigger for your user pool. When you do that you also need to set KMS key that Cognito will use. You can use aws-cli to do this.

References:

[Official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sms-sender.html)

Terraform currently does not support custom sms sender trigger. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16760) regarding this

[Aws cli update user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/update-user-pool.html)